# SP1 update for Visual Studio Express 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, ssms

I was trying to install SqlServer 2008 and got an error saying, that my Visual Studio (namely Visual C# 2008 Express) was not up-to-date, and it required VS 2008 SP1. The only update I have found on MS download site says that it doesn't work with Express Editions. How to update the Express Edition to SP1?

Besides, does Management Studio Express support working with Sql Compact (3.5) databases (sdf files)? That's actually what I need all this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to update the Express Edition to SP1?

<strike>You would just install the Express Edition with Service Pack 1 overtop of your existing Express product. You can download them [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14597).</strike>

It's recommended to update to [the latest version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) of Visual Studio Express as 2008 Express is no longer available.

> Besides, does Management Studio Express support working with Sql Compact databases (sdf files)?

Yes. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express (SSMSE) provides a graphical management tool for SQL Server 2008 Express (SQL Server Express), SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services, **and (SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1)**.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to VS Express 2008 with SP1 doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: ""It's recommended to update to the latest version of Visual Studio Express as 2008 Express is no longer available."" Yeah, MS gives that line because they want the devs that are not on Express to be buying a new license every 2 years. In an attempt to make the old version obsolete. MS changes enough of the synthax and standards between editions to make collaboration between two editions difficult. Those conversion tools only do 80% of the job but miss a whole bunch of stuff that you have hunt around for. If you're working with a codebase that was deved with VS2008 better off sticking with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to download Visual Studio 2008 Express SP-1

https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/visual-studio-2008/download

Comment: That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).